# How to execute a SELECT on a table with a list of composite keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

If I have a table with columns like

> ID1 ID2 VAL1 VAL2

Where ID1,ID2 makes the primary key index.

How do I execute any SQL statements for specific ID1,ID2 values?

Example: I have table with records that has PK (1,1) (1,2) (2,4) (2,1) (3,1) (3,2) (3,5)

I want to only select records with (1,1) (1,2) (3,5) (3,2)

A SELECT query with

> SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE ID1 IN (1,3) AND ID2 IN (1,2,5)

will yield undesired result: (3,1). So what's the best way to do this?

I am looking for an overall answer for SQL, but if it is dependent on the DBMS, I would like to know how to do so in PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both MySQL and PostgreSQL support tuples in `IN` as below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1
WHERE (ID1,ID2) IN ((1,1) (1,2) (2,4) (2,1) (3,1) (3,2) (3,5));
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. PostgreSQL also supports this syntax. However I'm wondering if it adheres to the left most prefix rules to utilise the primary key index.

Comment: @RonaldChan - You'd have to look at the explain plans. Can't imagine the construct would cause any particular problems to the respective optimisers but don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be the case at least in Postgres.

Comment: @RonaldChan: The primary key creates a multi-column on `(ID1, ID)`. As long as both columns are involved in the condition the index will be used equally effective. I wrote more, plus link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Nice answer in the link. I missed that first time round!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `and` and `or`:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    tbl1
WHERE   ID1 = 1 AND ID2 = 1 OR
        ID1 = 1 AND ID2 = 2 OR
        ID1 = 3 AND ID2 = 5 OR
        ID1 = 2 AND ID2 = 2
```

Comment: Presumably this is the only way? And it would still use the primary key index? It suddenly seems like SQL has an inefficient language barrier when dealing with composite keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most compact way of doing what you requested:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
WHERE (ID1 = 1 AND (ID2 = 1 OR ID2 = 2))
   OR (ID1 = 3 AND (ID2 = 5 OR ID2 = 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE ID1 = 1 AND ID2 IN (1,2)
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE ID1 = 3 AND ID2 IN (5,2)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE (ID1 = 1 AND ID2 IN (1,2)) OR (ID1 = 3 AND ID2 IN (5,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
  tbl1
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT 1 AS ID1, 1 AS ID2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS ID1, 2 AS ID2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID1, 4 AS ID2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID1, 1 AS ID2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID1, 1 AS ID2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID1, 2 AS ID2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID1, 5 AS ID2
  ) as keylist ON tbl1.ID1 = keylist.ID1 AND tbl1.ID2 = keylist.ID2
```

Comment: If anybody should want to use this monstrous construct, be sure to make it [UNION ALL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION). Also, there is no need to provide column alias in any but the first union-`SELECT`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for the UNION ALL heads up, i forgot the negligible performance benefit you would get in this case as the results set is so small.  The reason i leave the field names in is for readability. This is because it is my belief that the objective of the code should be clear within the actual code. A programmer should only focus on performance when this is the improvement required..